# Select2 - disabling dropdown after clearing the option

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

Im using Select2 plugin. My problem is simple - I dont want the dropdown list to show up when Im clearing the option.

Here is my code:

```html
<select class="select2-test" style="width: 20%;">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
 <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<script>
$('.select2-test').select2({
 placeholder: "Choose 1 option",
 allowClear: true
});
</script>
```

I have tried to delete this line from the select2.min.js:

```js
this.on("close",function(){a.$container.removeClass("select2-container--open")})
```

But it didnt help - the dropdown list wont show up after using it once. Any help will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you not to edit the original js folder.
By the way, you can use this, triggering with a click:

$('select').select2("close");

Or you can use the event **select2-removing** or/and **select2-removed**, which is a better solution I think (with an event.preventDefault or return false, as you want).

Comment: Could you show me some example with event.preventDefault? I tried something like this: $(".select2-selection__clear").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
}); but it didnt work.

Comment: I have found the example here: http://select2.github.io/select2/ In section Placeholders it works as I want after clearing the option. But why?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood something but, which type of select you want ? Multiple choice or single one ?

Comment: Both.;) I just don't want the dropdown menu to be displayed when I press this tiny "X" to clear option like in Select2 3.5.3 version. Is this possible to do it in 4.0.0 version?

Comment: I found this jsfiddle which, I think, will help you. It seems to work !

http://jsfiddle.net/obq3yLf2/

Comment: Let us know if you found the solution !